# Is there a way to ALWAYS convert string data member in Entity Model to char(n)?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Application has multiple tables - entity model classes, many of them have string data member and respective column type is char[n].

While debugging I found that Entity Framework Core default converts string to "nchar(n)" type. Since actual db column type is char(n), indices are not working properly and there is a performance hit.

Is there a way to change this default behavior (convert string to nchar(n))?

I don't want to manually go in each entity model class change like this,

property.HasColumnType("char").HasMaxLength(length).IsFixedLength();